# Split Date/Time value for Night Shift Employee

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is a follow up to my previous question:

[First-In and Last-Out times for Night Shift Employees](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/127715/1192)

I am a beginner in SQL. I tried this query and CTE, but I cannot get my desired output:

```
 SELECT UserId, Convert(varchar(10),LogDate,120) as [Date],
   Min(CASE WHEN (C1 = 'out') THEN LogDate END) AS [Login],
   MAX(CASE WHEN (C1 = 'in') THEN LogDate END) AS [Logout] FROM Employee 
  GROUP BY UserId,Convert(varchar(10),LogDate,120) ORDER BY UserId
```

#### Shift Table

```
        UserID   ShiftName      Start   End  
    ---------------------------------------------------   
        1019     Night Shift-1  18:30   03:30
```

#### Employee Table

```
     UserID      LogDate                         C1
    ---------------------------------------------------
     1019        2016-03-01 05:17:03.000         Out
     1019        2016-03-01 18:41:14.000         In
     1019        2016-03-01 22:06:24.000         Out
     1019        2016-03-01 22:34:03.000         In
     1019        2016-03-02 01:32:33.000         Out
     1019        2016-03-02 01:38:03.000         In
     1019        2016-03-02 05:32:33.000         Out
```

#### Desired output Table1:

```
    UserId  Date           LogIN                  LogOUT
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
    1019    2016-03-01     2016-03-01 18:41:14    2016-03-01 22:06:24 
    1019    2016-03-01     2016-03-01 22:34:03    2016-03-02 01:32:33
    1019    2016-03-01     2016-03-02 01:38:03    2016-03-02 05:32:33
```

#### Desired output Table2:

```
  UserId   Date           FirstIN                LastOUT               Working Hours
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1019     2016-03-01     2016-03-01 18:41:14    2016-03-02 05:32:33      ?
```

Additional notes:

- There may be multiple IN and OUT for each employee.
- The shift times are 18:30 and 03:30.
- Employees may come maximum 2 hours earlier or leave 2 hours later.

Comment: And how do you know when a user changes to a different shift? I'm sure that happens? You'll say we change the row in the shift table, but then you'll use the new shift times to calculate yesterday or the day before, but in reality they were on the old shift time.

Comment: It doesnt matter. Because I already fixed this issue. I can able to get Current Date Employee Shift time. That is the Big Process. I have done earlier.

Comment: What happens if someone forgets to clock out?

Comment: @Erik:  Employee's  Manager can Edited  in Attendance table with acceptable Reason. That will approved by senior person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (UserID int, LogDate datetime, C1 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO @Employee (UserID, LogDate, C1) VALUES
(1019, '2016-03-01 05:17:03.000', 'Out'),
(1019, '2016-03-01 18:41:14.000', 'In'),
(1019, '2016-03-01 22:06:24.000', 'Out'),
(1019, '2016-03-01 22:34:03.000', 'In'),
(1019, '2016-03-02 01:32:33.000', 'Out'),
(1019, '2016-03-02 01:38:03.000', 'In'),
(1019, '2016-03-02 05:32:33.000', 'Out');

DECLARE @Shifts TABLE (UserID int, ShiftName varchar(50), ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight int);
INSERT INTO @Shifts (UserID, ShiftName, ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight) VALUES
(1019, 'Night Shift-1', 18*60 + 30 - 2*60); -- 18:30 minus 2 hours
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
    EIn.UserID
    ,CAST(DATEADD(minute, -ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight, EIn.LogDate) AS date) AS dt
    ,EIn.LogDate AS LogIn
    ,CA_Out.LogDate AS LogOut
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, EIn.LogDate, CA_Out.LogDate) AS WorkingMinutes
FROM
    @Employee AS EIn
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) EOut.LogDate
        FROM @Employee AS EOut
        WHERE
            EOut.UserID = EIn.UserID
            AND EOut.C1 = 'Out'
            AND EOut.LogDate >= EIn.LogDate
        ORDER BY EOut.LogDate
    ) AS CA_Out
    INNER JOIN @Shifts AS S ON S.UserID = EIn.UserID
WHERE
    EIn.C1 = 'In'
ORDER BY
    UserID
    ,LogIn
;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| UserID |     dt     |          LogIn          |         LogOut          | WorkingMinutes |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|   1019 | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-01 18:41:14.000 | 2016-03-01 22:06:24.000 |            205 |
|   1019 | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-01 22:34:03.000 | 2016-03-02 01:32:33.000 |            178 |
|   1019 | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-02 01:38:03.000 | 2016-03-02 05:32:33.000 |            234 |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

**Logic**

At first we select all rows that have `C1 = 'In'` - all instances when a person came in.

Then we use `CROSS APPLY` to find one matching `Out` row. Make sure that the `Employee` table has an index on `(UserID, C1, LogDate)`, otherwise the query will be inefficient. This gives us `LogIn` and `LogOut` columns.

The `dt` column is based on the `LogIn` timestamp. Instead of having start and end times in the `Shifts` table, I would store only the offset of the shift start - the number of minutes past midnight which sets the boundary of the shift. In your example it is `18*60 + 30` minus 2 hours, because you said that the person can come two hours earlier. If the person comes more than 2 hours earlier, it will be considered a previous day. The time when shift ends doesn't matter (as long as the shift is less than 24 hours long). The `ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight` is subtracted from the `LogIn` timestamp and result is cast to `date` to truncate hours/minutes/seconds.

---

The second summary result can be obtained from the first with a simple grouping by user and date.

**Query 2**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        EIn.UserID
        ,CAST(DATEADD(minute, -ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight, EIn.LogDate) AS date) AS dt
        ,EIn.LogDate AS LogIn
        ,CA_Out.LogDate AS LogOut
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, EIn.LogDate, CA_Out.LogDate) AS WorkingMinutes
    FROM
        @Employee AS EIn
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(1) EOut.LogDate
            FROM @Employee AS EOut
            WHERE
                EOut.UserID = EIn.UserID
                AND EOut.C1 = 'Out'
                AND EOut.LogDate >= EIn.LogDate
            ORDER BY EOut.LogDate
        ) AS CA_Out
        INNER JOIN @Shifts AS S ON S.UserID = EIn.UserID
    WHERE
        EIn.C1 = 'In'
)
SELECT
    UserID
    ,dt
    ,MIN(LogIn) AS FirstIn
    ,MAX(LogOut) AS LastOut
    ,SUM(WorkingMinutes)/60.0 AS WorkingHours
FROM CTE
GROUP BY UserID, dt
ORDER BY UserID, dt
;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| UserID |     dt     |         FirstIn         |         LastOut         | WorkingHours |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|   1019 | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-01 18:41:14.000 | 2016-03-02 05:32:33.000 | 10.283333    |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```